# How to deal with a large number (20+) of SettingKeys related to a TaskKey?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm currently in the process of finishing the **SBT plugin** for [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org).

Flyway has 6 basic commands which will map to 6 TaskKeys.

These can be configured by a large number of setters (20+) on the Flyway object. Each of these settings would then map to a SettingKey (one per setter).

I am however hitting a **limit in the number of parameters** I can pass when resolving the TaskKey. Is there a better/more scalable (as in supporting even more SettingKeys) to solve this? Or to put it more generally:

What is the best way to deal with a **large number of SettingKeys related to a TaskKey**?

Answer (score 1):

A work around is to bundle multiple related keys into auxiliary objects. E.g. [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-appbundle/blob/e0ff30f0d89668ab759112b27cb16c6566c89d0f/src/main/scala/de/sciss/sbt/appbundle/AppBundlePlugin.scala#L83) I am creating a helper key `"_aux_java"` to handle the problem:

```
private val java      = TaskKey[JavaSettings]("_aux_java")
...

val settings = Seq[Setting[_]](
  ...
  java      <<= (systemProperties, javaOptions, fullClasspath, packageBin in Compile,
                 mainClass, javaVersion, javaArchs, workingDirectory) map JavaSettings,
  appbundle <<= (infos, java, bundle, streams) map appbundleTask
)
...

case class JavaSettings(systemProperties: Seq[(String, String)],
                        javaOptions: Seq[String], classpath: Classpath, jarFile: File,
                        mainClassOption: Option[String], javaVersion: String,
                        javaArchs: Seq[String], workingDirectory: Option[File])
```

So that one captures already eight related keys into one aux objects. You can repeat this for other groups.

Answer (score 0):

I pass 'state' artument to task and extract all SettingKeys directly from there.

As example:
https://github.com/digimead/sbt-dependency-manager/blob/master/src/main/scala/sbt/dependency/manager/Plugin.scala

IMHO there will be alternative way in 0.13 but you better to search against sbt mailing list.

PS I plan to support 0.12 a long as needed so this is the only solution for me.